# Check if time is today or tomorrow

Tags: mysql, sql, time

In MySQL, I have three columns (`IsActive`, `OpenTime` and `CloseTime`) in a `restaurant` table. I have added a CRON job to identify restaurants which needs to be opened or closed, and then I update the status accordingly. Let's suppose I have following data:

```
IsActive |OpenTime |CloseTime
---------|---------|---------
1        |13:00    |1:00
0        |8:00     |20:00
```

Following is the SQL:

```
SELECT * from `restaurant`
WHERE
  (
    IsActive = 0
    AND
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', `OpenTime`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < NOW()
  )
  OR
  (
    IsActive = 1
    AND
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', `CloseTime`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < NOW()
  )
```

Everything works well, but logic fails when the closing date is on next day, as you know after 11:59PM it's next day, but in `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', OpenTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')` the `CURDATE()` is today and I don't know how to make it next day. Due to this the 1st row toggles to 1 and 0 whenever the CRON runs. Because `1:00` on today is less than the current time.

Comment: after applying `STR_TO_DATE`, check if `CloseTime` < `OpenTime`, +1 day to `CloseTime`

Comment: @ProGu can you write up that in the answer? I got your point but can't figure it out :(

Comment: Using a cronjob to continually update the IsActive status of the restaurant is a horrible idea. You could create the IsActive column as a generated column (or view) with the logic provided by Salman A

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong about being able to use CURRENT_TIME in a generated column (only deterministic functions) but it can definitely be used in an equivalent view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never noticed what @ProGu said on the first place. I have been scratching my head for 2 days. Now I thought let's give a try to his logic. And it worked like a charm. I followed @Salman suggestion not to run CRON job and load active restaurants on demand and used @ProGu logic, here's what my final query look like:

```
SELECT * from `restaurant`
WHERE
(
  NOW() > STR_TO_DATE(`OpenTime`, '%H:%i')
  AND
  NOW() <
    CASE
      WHEN STR_TO_DATE(`OpenTime`, '%H:%i') > STR_TO_DATE(`CloseTime`, '%H:%i')
        THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(`CloseTime`, '%H:%i'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      ELSE STR_TO_DATE(`CloseTime`, '%H:%i')
    END
)
```

Thanks guys for the great help. Special thanks to Salman for writing up the answer, which motivated me to leave cron job and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The logic to check if current time is between two times (which could be on opposite side of midnight) is simple:

- If OpenTime <= CloseTime then check if OpenTime <= CURRENT_TIME And CURRENT_TIME < CloseTime
- Else check if OpenTime <= CURRENT_TIME Or CURRENT_TIME < CloseTime

That being said, you don't need the active column. Just query the active restaurants on demand.

Comment: Hey! Your condition is wrong, I tried with many examples, let say, start = 08:00, end = 20:00, curr = 02:00 now check your condition, it says TRUE, but it's 2AM restaurant should be open.

Comment: I don't get it. Regarding your first comment: restaurant should be closed at 2am and my query returns false i.e. not open.

Comment: oh ok I got it, `OpenTime <= CURRENT_TIME And CURRENT_TIME < CloseTime` is nested in 1st `if`, so if it false than no need to go to else. I was reading it wrong.